# MySQL ORM - conditional WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'm using `sequelize` as a MySQL ORM and i have the following code:

```
 mysql().lib.query("SELECT t.id, t.address
                    FROM mytable t 
                    WHERE t.fname = :fname OR t.lname = :lname",
          replacements: { fname, lname })
```

`fname` and `lname` are variables that are potentially not set in the code, or set to `null`.
So my question is - how can i use one or both of them inside of the `WHERE` clause but only if they "exist"?

(Note: at least one of them will definitely exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with simple boolean logic

```
WHERE (:fname is null or t.fname = :fname) 
  AND (:lname is null or t.lname = :lname)
   ^------ I used AND here since it does make more sense
```

Comment: With this, how would the query look like if `fname = null`? it shouldn't be a part of the `WHERE` clause in that case right?

Comment: Ohhh so in that case `:fname is null` would evaluate to `true` which would result it `WHERE true` which "doesn't do anything"?

Comment: Also - why are you using `AND` and not `OR`?

Comment: Do you want to match just one of the values? First name OR last name? Or do you want to match both - first name AND last name. The last choice makes sense, right?